# jpa criteria seems to work (or not) depending on whether db is mysql or objectdb

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, objectdb

When I use JPA with MySQL, the below query works fine. But when I use it with ObjectDB, it throws the exception below.

```
public Friendship getFriendship(String username) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Friendship> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Friendship.class);
    Root<Friendship> root = query.from(Friendship.class); 
    Path<String> path = root.<String>get("username");
    query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(path, username));
    return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

The error from the browser

```
 type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.objectdb.o._PersistenceException: Unexpected query token 'FROM' (SELECT is expected)
root cause

com.objectdb.o._PersistenceException: Unexpected query token 'FROM' (SELECT is expected)
root cause

com.objectdb.o.UserException: Unexpected query token 'FROM' (SELECT is expected)
```

Comment: It's EclipseLink. But I thought JPA, which is the java interface, was supposed to be implementation blind? Does the implementation matter?

Comment: CORRECTION: For the `objectdb` version I am using `com.objectdb.jpa.Provider`. For the `MySQL` version I am using `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`. Apparently, they are both `EclipseLink`.

Comment: Try adding `criteriaBuilder.select(root);` before executing query.

Comment: There is a `criteriaBuilder.selectCase(root);` option. But when I add it, there is no difference.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Add query.select(root); I guess.

Comment: @kasavbere So does this mean that the query did NOT work in mysql after all?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above correctly (and as shown by the error message) - a select is missing.

A valid JPQL query must include SELECT, otherwise the query is incomplete.

Some JPA implementations extend the standard JPQL by supporting queries with no SELECT.